# Rearrange values of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this 2 arrays

```
array1 = (Q1, Q2)
array2 = (ansA1,ansB1,ansC1,ansD1,ansA2,ansB2,ansC2,ansD2)
```

I merged these 2 arrays using array_merge
so its now

```
combine_array = (Q1,Q2,ansA1,ansB1,ansC1,ansD1,ansA2,ansB2,ansC2,ansD2)
```

I need to rearrange these arrays where in the Q2 will be place before 'ansA2'
I know it can be done easily when specifying the key value, but What if it has more values inside the arrays? eg,. Q1, to Q10, etc.. Thanks for the help

Comment: I suspect there is a better way to approach the problem - in particular, objects with a "Question" and "Answer" member may be more appropriate. (These can then be easily flattened/walked.)

Comment: If you’re looking for a keys-to-values thing, that would be [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine).

Comment: array_combine is good but the problem is, it need to have same number of elements,

Comment: Why on earth do you want to store your data that way?  You could do this much easier with a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I am posting 2 array data,. I have problems with displaying it on the PDF,. when I used array_combine, It has error "error should have equal elements". So what I did, I used array_merge so I will post the data on order,. but the problem is, when you merge the two arrays, it is adding to the end of the first array, so it does not get the output I need.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have a keys-to-values mapping, but flat, and any values without keys should be put at the end of the array?

Okay. We can abuse `array_map` for that.

```
$result = [];

array_map(function($key, $value) use (&$result) {
    if ($key !== null) {
        array_push($result, $key);
    }

    array_push($result, $value);
}, $keys, $values);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7jsogV)

I suppose it can be made a bit cleaner (or at least 5.2-compatible) with a `MultipleIterator`:

```
$result = [];

$iter = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY);
$iter->attachIterator($keys);
$iter->attachIterator($values);

foreach ($iter as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = $pair;

    if ($key !== null) {
        array_push($result, $key);
    }

    array_push($result, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more sensible approach to this would be

```
$questions[1]['question'] = "What is 2 + 2?";
$questions[1]['answers']['a'] = 1;
$questions[1]['answers']['b'] = 2;
$questions[1]['answers']['c'] = 3;
$questions[1]['answers']['d'] = 4;

$questions[2]['question'] = "What is 3 + 3?";
$questions[2]['answers']['a'] = 2;
$questions[2]['answers']['b'] = 4;
$questions[2]['answers']['c'] = 6;
$questions[2]['answers']['d'] = 8;
```

Or even as simple as this

```
$questions[1]['question'] = "What is 2 + 2?";
$questions[1]['a'] = 1;
$questions[1]['b'] = 2;
$questions[1]['c'] = 3;
$questions[1]['d'] = 4;
```

Comment: Yes this post explains my questions well, thank you for explaining my questions very well..

Comment: I was hoping to answer your question well, but I guess I can live with explaining it well.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm… Not too sure if you are working with associative arrays or not, but whipped this up based on your literal question of merging two flat arrays as described.

```
$array1 = array('Q1', 'Q2');
$array2 = array('ansA1','ansB1','ansC1','ansD1','ansA2','ansB2','ansC2','ansD2');

$combine_array = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
  $combine_array[] = $value1;
  foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    if ("Q" . preg_replace('/[^0-9]/is', '', $value2) == $value1) {
      $combine_array[] = $value2;
    }
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($combine_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output of that `print_r()` should be as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Q1
    [1] => ansA1
    [2] => ansB1
    [3] => ansC1
    [4] => ansD1
    [5] => Q2
    [6] => ansA2
    [7] => ansB2
    [8] => ansC2
    [9] => ansD2
)
```

Another idea I have is to create an associative array with the question array values as the key, and the answers in an array value connected to that key.  Like so:

```
$array1 = array('Q1', 'Q2');
$array2 = array('ansA1','ansB1','ansC1','ansD1','ansA2','ansB2','ansC2','ansD2');

$combine_array = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
  $answer_array = array();
  foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    if ("Q" . preg_replace('/[^0-9]/is', '', $value2) == $value1) {
      $answer_array[] = $value2;
    }
    $combine_array[$value1] = $answer_array;
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($combine_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [Q1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ansA1
            [1] => ansB1
            [2] => ansC1
            [3] => ansD1
        )

    [Q2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ansA2
            [1] => ansB2
            [2] => ansC2
            [3] => ansD2
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi, Im sorry, if I understand your answer correctly,. uhmm but the Q1, Q2 is just a sample values.. the post of  @dockeryZ seems explained my questions. But thx anyway,